# Missing number treated as Zero - Empty cells in PGFplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

I am working on a table where I need to deal with empty cells. The example is given below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs, colortbl}

\pgfplotstableset{col sep=semicolon, use comma, fixed, set thousands separator={}, 
    every even row/.style={before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}}, 
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}}

\newcommand{\addsumcol}[3]{ %
% #1=table name
% #2=first column name
% #3=name of new column
% Sums for each column
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[%
create col/assign/.code={%
    \def\entry{}
        \def\colsum{0}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\maxcolindex{\pgfplotstablecols-1}
        \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \col in {#2,...,\maxcolindex}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro\colsum{\colsum+\thisrowno{\col}}
        }
        \xdef\entry{\colsum}
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
}
]{#3}#1
}%

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
ID; Points 1; Points 2; Points 3 
1010121; 1.0; 1; 3
1010122; 1.0; 2; 4
1010123; 5.0; 3; 5
1010124; 5.0; 4; 6
1010125; 3.0; 5; 
1010126; 4.0; 6; 8
1010127; 2.5; 7; 9
}\Marks

\addsumcol{\Marks}{1}{Sum}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={ID, Points 1, Points 2, Points 3, Sum}, 
columns/Mark/.style={numeric type, fixed zerofill, precision=1}]\Marks

\end{document}
```

The problem is that I keep getting an error saying

> Missing number, treated as zero. \addsumcol{\Marks}{1}{Sum}

Despite this, the output for this small example looks fine.

[image]

With a bigger one the table is not generated any more an I can't find out where the problem is since there are too many of theses errors.

I found some hints here using several other packages like *xstring* to check if the cell is empty with `\IfStrEq{}{}{}` before trying to add the value, but I didn't found out why it was not working.

Since I want to check later on if there are empty cells for a decision to not show the complete row or to mark it so that somebody has to give the missing value if there is an empty cell left, I don't want to replace the empty cells with a zero before using the `\addsumcol{\Marks}{1}{Sum}`.

I would really appreciate to get any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion using package `xstring`:

```
\IfStrEq{\thisrowno{\col}}{}% check if the cell is empty
  {}% true
  {\pgfmathsetmacro\colsum{\colsum+\thisrowno{\col}}}% false
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs, colortbl}

\pgfplotstableset{col sep=semicolon, use comma, fixed, set thousands separator={}, 
    every even row/.style={before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}}, 
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}}

\newcommand{\addsumcol}[3]{%
% #1=table name
% #2=first column name
% #3=name of new column
% Sums for each column
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[%
create col/assign/.code={%
    \def\entry{}%
        \def\colsum{0}%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\maxcolindex{\pgfplotstablecols-1}%
        \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \col in {#2,...,\maxcolindex}{%
            \IfStrEq{\thisrowno{\col}}{}% check if the cell is empty
              {}% true
              {\pgfmathsetmacro\colsum{\colsum+\thisrowno{\col}}}% false
        }%
        \xdef\entry{\colsum}%
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
}
]{#3}#1%
}%

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
ID; Points 1; Points 2; Points 3 
1010121; 1.0; 1; 3
1010122; 1.0; 2; 4
1010123; 5.0; 3; 5
1010124; 5.0; 4; 6
1010125; 3.0; 5;
1010126; 4.0; 6; 8
1010127; 2.5; 7; 9
}\Marks
\addsumcol{\Marks}{1}{Sum}%
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={ID, Points 1, Points 2, Points 3, Sum}, 
columns/Mark/.style={numeric type, fixed zerofill, precision=1}]\Marks
\end{document}
```

Note that I have removed some spurious spaces.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought I tried it like that but for me it didn't worked. Maybe it was just a little fault. Now it is working. :-)